# console.log of undefined doesn't log

Tags: javascript

I am trying to fetch data from www.matchbook.com using this script

```
function scrape(){
  var row = document.querySelectorAll(".mb-runner")[0]; //get rows
  console.log(row.textContent); //log row content
}setInterval(scrape, 1000);
```

This code produces inline data ***ArsenalArsenal1.347$2591.349$20,8171.352$4811.363$11,2331.368$11,4571.379$9,948*** without delimiter. Do you know how should I separate this data?

Here I am posting screen how data looks on a web
[image]

Comment: well sounds like it is selecting a cell that has the class..... My guess is when it is empty it does not have the class....

Comment: The logging code can't log a different cell than the one you selected. Can you provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem (I'm not sure what you're suggesting we do at the matchbook.com site)?

Comment: @epascarello Good point. Maybe it is that type of problem.

Comment: @Barmar for example https://www.matchbook.com/events/tennis/wta-charleston/r2/767327600410014/live-betting/f-stollar-vs-j-konta I didn't post concrete url because betting is closed frequently so I decided to mention only matchobook.com where you can try to log betting table you want.

Comment: @Barmar The logging code really logs different cell than I selected. You can try it.

Comment: I still don't understand what I'm supposed to do to see the problem. I pasted your code into the console, every second it logged 4.25. What should I see instead?

Comment: @Barmar It's ok that it logs data. It's great but when a number value dissapear from a table (better visit live betting, it's constantly changing) you will see that console.log logs next table cell.

Comment: For a few seconds, the first cell changed to "Make offer", and then your script showed the price from the second cell. Is this what you're talking about? I haven't been able to catch it when this repeats and examine the DOM, but I assume that when this happens it doesn't have `class="mb-price__odds"`, so the selector doesn't match that cell.

Comment: Sounds like you need to come up with a different selector that finds the cell by its position in the table, not based on the class.

Comment: @Barmar Exactly. I have to figure out how to handle this "Make offer" thing.

Comment: @Barmar You know how to select it better? I do not.

Comment: I just posted an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved my problem via this javascript code:

```
function scrape(){
  var radek = document.querySelectorAll(".mb-runner")[2];//row
  var bunka = radek.querySelectorAll(".mb-price")[0]; //cell
  console.log(bunka.textContent); //cell value
}setInterval(scrape, 1000); //run every second
```

Answer (score 0):

When the contents of that cell changes to `MAKE OFFER`, it no longer has the `mb-price__odds` class, so the selector matches the next cell.

Instead of selecting by this cell's class, use the class of the container, which I don't think goes away.

Then check whether this matched anything before trying to access `.textContents`.

```
function scrape() {
  var cell = document.querySelector(".mb-price:first-of-type .mb-price__odds");
  if (!cell) {
    console.log("Log me null please, do not skip to another cell !");
  } else {
    console.log(cell.textContents);
  }
}
```

Comment: You've changed the question! Where did `.mb-runner` come from, what happened to `.mb-price__odds`?

Comment: I deeply focused on page structure and find out that would be better to target whole table, than whole row and than whole cell instead of hard class targeting that was unefficient. Now my script logs data I want but now I have to find a way how to console.logged data exports to some *.txt file

Comment: If you're doing this as a browser extension, maybe it can display this in another browser window instead of using console.log and then you can save the window to a file.

Comment: Can you please explain how? :) I don't use any browser extension.

Comment: I'm suggesting that you write a browser extension containing this code. There are tutorials on how to write extensions, I'm not going to try to explain it here.

Comment: Now I get you. Thank you for advice.

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

No need to `querySelectorAll` if you only need the first element

Find the parent first and look for the price only if the element exists

Put null check on the element && the text content

```
function scrape(){
  var x = document.querySelector(".mb-price");
  var y = x && x.querySelector('.mb-price__odds');
  if (y && y.textContent){ 
    console.log(y.textContent);
  }
  else {
    console.log('No Content');
  }
}
```